# TSQL/SSRS - Parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

i'm trying to build a report, in which the report itself can be manipulated by the user. The user can click on a text ("No" and "Yes") in the column "Appraisal" and the report will forward parameters to itself and change a value of the Column "Enable" in the table. I build a stored procedure for this:

```
USE [TestDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Test]    Script Date: 05.07.2022 09:08:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @NR int,
     @UpdateValue Tinyint,
     @Month varchar(MAX)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)



SET @SQL ='

IF ' + CAST(@UpdateValue AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' = 1

BEGIN
IF (Select Enable from [Testdb].[dbo].[test_table] where CAST(Month as varchar(6)) = cast( ''' +CAST(@Month as varchar(6))+''' as varchar(50))  and NR = cast( ''' + CAST(@NR AS VARCHAR(50)) +''' as int)) = 0  
    BEGIN
        Update [Testdb].[dbo].[test_table] Set ENABLE = 1 WHERE CAST(Moth as varchar(6)) = cast( ''' +CAST(@Month as varchar(6))+''' as varchar(50)) and ENABLE = 0 and NR = cast( ''' + CAST(@NR AS VARCHAR(50)) +''' as int)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        Update [Testdb].[dbo].[test_table] Set ENABLE = 0 WHERE CAST(Monat as varchar(6)) =cast( ''' +CAST(@Month as varchar(6))+''' as varchar(50)) and ENABLE = 1 and NR = cast( ''' + CAST(@NR AS VARCHAR(50)) +''' as int)
    END
END



SELECT [ID1]
      ,[ID2]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Team]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Month]
      ,[Week]
      ,[column1]
      ,[column2]
      ,[column3]
      ,[reason]
      ,[NR]
      ,[Enable]  into ##temptest
      
      FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[test_table] 
      '

PRINT @sql

Execute(@SQL)




SELECT * FROM ##temptest
DROP TABLE ##temptest
END
```

If i assign the parameter now in my tablix, start the report and click on a text i get the following error:

```
Procedure or function 'sp_Test' expects parameter '@Month', which was not supplied.
```

I tried different changes on my procedure without success. Since it's my first time using a procedure, i'm struggling to locate the source of error. In the report, i use an extra dataset for the parameter, with the same data type and format (e.g. 202206).

Without the month parameter, the process works fine the way it should.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: hi @NewbieSQL_Germany, I have copied your code and adapted it in my database and if I execute in SSMS `exec [dbo].[sp_Test] 1,1,'January'` works, are you sure that after click in the text "Yes No" are you calling the SP with the 3 parameters ?. Other way to find out the issue is asign a value like this `alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Test]    @NR int = 1, @UpdateValue Tinyint = 1,@Month varchar(MAX) = 'January'` in that case is not necesary pass all parameters for example  `exec [dbo].[sp_Test] 1,1` , if its works meaning that you don't pass all parameters from the tablix

Comment: hi pfigueredo, well, that's how easy it can be. Your solution was the right one, i didn't pass all three parameters. Thanks a lot for your help!